# Options to define link HREF

Tags: href

Is there a way to specify a link to say don't navigate.  There is an option to specify href="#".  But if the link output is directed to a target this will cause the calling page to be loaded in that target.

In a file called load.php I have these links defined for folder nodes in a navigation tree.

```
<a href="#"> link </a>
```

The page nodes under the folders have

```
<a href="page.html">page link</a>
```

Each link in the navigation tree is directed to a content area.

Here is the problem. If I click on a folder, the href="#" causes the tree page to be loaded in the content area.  I want to specify the href to not load anything in the content area for the folders.  I have a workaround where I load a blank page.  But if there is a different way I would prefer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with JavaScript. Specifically you can load the jQuery library and do something like this:

```
$("a[href='#']").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```